# How to send the list of receivers of a actionmailer method to a different email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Following is the my ActionMailer method for sending some bulk emails to receivers.

```
def mail_to
 @default_email = "user@gmail.com"
 @receivers #contains the array of all the receivers
 mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail) if @receiver.present?
end
```

This is working fine. But now I wanted to send the `@default_email` all the list of receivers in `@receivers` variable in the form of text or a list. Is there a way I can achieve this within the same method without having to create another actionmailer method just for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass @receivers variable in template and added condition so that only @default_email can see @receiver variable. eg

## template

```
<% if user.email == "user@gmail.com" %>
  <% @receivers.each do |r| %>
    <%= r.email %>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```